# How to Overlay a Widget on top of another

Tags: flutter

I have an app that looks like this

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed:() {
          // Want pop up to launch
        },
      ),
    )
  }
}

class PopUp extends StatefulWidget {
  PopUp({
    this.postId
  })

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PopUpState();
}

class PopUpState extends State<PopUp> {
  // api logic

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Dialog()
  }
}
```

Is it possible for me to overlay the `PopUp` widget on top of the MainScreen Widget without using showDialog ? Since i'm trying to make the PopUp stateful in that it processes and rerenders itself depending on the processed data ?

Comment: How does `showDialog` prevents you from making a stateful dialog ?

Comment: Can you describe the scenario a bit that requires the dialog to be stateful to help direct answers appropriately?

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet wasn't quite sure the showDialog would rerender well enough if i were to setState() repeatedly while still showing it and the content in the back.

Comment: @DerekLakin Currently have a Post in which a user can only read depending on a different variables which are being confirmed through the java platform as such i wanted a popup of sorts that showed the user the validation process as its ongoing and warns them if they don't meet the requirements but redirect them if they do.

Comment: If it's information on the screen while the user is doing something else, then a bottom sheet might be more appropriate that a Dialog: https://www.material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html

However, if a Dialog is the right approach, then calling setState on the dialog should affect whether it's open or not until the user completes the dialog action.

Comment: @DerekLakin i'm going to assume you meant "shouldn't affect" ?

Comment: @DerekLakin Would it be the same with a simple dialog ? with no actions ? Since the dialog will have no actions till the 3rd phase( Later on into its initialization ).

Comment: Yes, I meant "shouldn't affect", sorry :)
Sounds like you want to present information to the user during a process, rather than blocking them from doing something else. A Dialog is appropriate for a blocking action (i.e. needing confirmation, making a choice, etc), but a bottom sheet would be more appropriate for showing a progress/process update. Does that make sense?